# how to clear chatterbot knowledge base in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, corpus, chatterbot

After installing **chatterbot** i have trained the bot for some couple of times through corpus data provided within the **chatterbot** and also using some of my own conversation list. After that when i trained the bot with some corpus data written by me. Then when i am trying to talk with the bot it is answering from its knowledge base. So if somebody could tell me where can i find this knowledge base data or how can i **clear the knowledge base data created by chatterbot**

Comment: If you are using the default SQL storage configuration, there should be a .sqlite3 file that was created relative to the location of your code. Deleting this file will delete all of the learned content.

Comment: @Gunther as of now i am using the corpus dataset provided there. But thanks for the information though. In future i am going to shift to mongodb. But as of now i want to know how to clear the knowledge base if it was made through corpus data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChatterBot stores the conversational dialog it learns in whatever database you are using it with.

One common way to remove all content from the database is like this:

```
chatbot = ChatBot("...")
chatbot.storage.drop()
```

The 'drop' function will empty the content from the database your chat bot is using.